# Does E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y] apply on different sample spaces?

Tags: statistics

Does $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ apply even when $X$ and $Y$ are defined on different sample spaces? If so, what does $X+Y$ mean??

Answer (score 5):

No, this formula is not valid if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on different sample spaces. If $X$ and $Y$ are defined on different sample spaces, then $X + Y$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

That's precisely the issue: $X+Y$ does not make sense. Because if $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, a random variable is a measurable function $X\colon \Omega \to \Bbb R$. If $Y$ is another, you want to define what is $(X+Y)(\omega)$, for $\omega \in \Omega$. And of course the operation is inherited from $\Bbb R$ and we set $(X+Y)(\omega) \doteq X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$. If you cannot evaluate $X$ and $Y$ in elements of the same sample space to begin with, there's no way to define the sum.